# 'WCF Data Services' template missing in Visual Studio 2015 Express edition

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, visual-studio-2015

I tried Nuget, but the browser pane stays empty. I also ran the [WCF Data Services 5.6.0 RTM Tools Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=39373), but the template is still missing.

Must I proceed in te Nuget direction? Or can I install WCF Data Services in an other way?

Regards,
Henk

Answer (score 0):

Might be a way, worked for me but... Your mileage might vary :)

I have VS 2015 Update 3 Community and Web Developer Tools are installed, but no WCF Templates (where) available.

I ran `devenv /installvstemplates` as normal user (in the directory where VS is installed) and got some generic error message.
Then i ran it **as admin** and it did *something* (i saw files disappearing and reappearing in an open explorer window).
After Starting VS there where only 3 templates available, and i thought i really screwed it up but after running it as admin once all templates where back!

Had the idea from [here](https://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/missing-templates-in-visual-studio-installed-templates/).